# Label size_request in pygi(Gtk3) python

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk, gtk3, pygobject

Hello I'm porting a small pygtk application to Gtk3(pygi). My Python code is:

```
import pygtk
pygtk.require('2.0')
import gtk
label = gtk.Label()
label.set_text('Helloooooooooooooooo')
print(label.size_request()[1])
print(label.size_request()[0])
```

Then i run the code. It print 17 and 154
But Then I Added:

```
from gi import pygtkcompat 
pygtkcompat.enable() 
pygtkcompat.enable_gtk(version='3.0')
```

to the first, it print 0 and 0

Sorry for my bad English

Comment: This is far from being an application. Please read the [Python GTK+ 3 Tutorial](https://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html).

Comment: Try [get_size_request](http://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/index.html#Gtk-3.0/classes/Widget.html#Gtk.Widget.get_size_request)

Comment: get_size_request didn't work. it print -1

Comment: any updates on this? I have the same problem